# ¿Como guardar un archivo para el cliente en ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hola estoy haciendo un programa que genera un PDF pero no tengo conocimiento de como guardarlos en la parte del cliente. Si hay mas de por favor háganmelo saber y cual es la mejor.

Comment: nooo escribimal :C

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Buenas tardes manual, que versión de ASP.Net estás utilizando? Adicionalmente, podrías mostrarnos un poco el código de lo que deseas realizar para ayudarte?

Comment: Hola use el objeto HttpResponse mediante el metodo .Write() para poder enviar el dialogo de ruta. Mil gracias!!!